# Creating a stacked bar graph with varying categories

Tags: python, pandas, visualization

I have the following dataframe:

```
print(df)
                                   Keys                       Amount          Unit      Period
0                          [AWS Lambda]                 0.0988477846           USD  2021-04-01
1                  [AWS Step Functions]                     0.155275           USD  2021-04-01
2  [Amazon Simple Notification Service]                            0           USD  2021-04-01
3          [AWS Key Management Service]                 0.0028137778           USD  2021-05-01
4                          [AWS Lambda]                 0.3184488309           USD  2021-05-01
5                  [AWS Step Functions]                     0.806125           USD  2021-05-01
6                          [AWS Lambda]                 0.2898902517           USD  2021-05-25
7                  [AWS Step Functions]                     0.604075           USD  2021-05-25
```

I want to make a stacked bar graph, where I have the `Period` (dates) on the X axis and then the `Amount` number values for `Keys` in stacked bars.

The desired result is something along the lines of this:
[image]

The problem I have is that I have varying number of groups per `Period`. Some categories of `Keys` only show up once.

Plotting with simple code like `df.plot.bar(stacked=True)` either leaves out categories or date points.

If possible I want to solve this while using a pandas dataframe and its native plot function but it can also be with other libraries such as matplotlib.

Is there a different approach I should take to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) with [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) first:

```
df1 = df.explode('Keys').pivot_table(index='Period', 
                                     columns='Keys', 
                                     values='Amount', 
                                     aggfunc='sum')


print (df1)
Keys        AWS Key Management Service  AWS Lambda  AWS Step Functions  \
Period                                                                   
2021-04-01                         NaN    0.098848            0.155275   
2021-05-01                    0.002814    0.318449            0.806125   
2021-05-25                         NaN    0.289890            0.604075   

Keys        Amazon Simple Notification Service  
Period                                          
2021-04-01                                 0.0  
2021-05-01                                 NaN  
2021-05-25                                 NaN  

df1.plot.bar(stacked=True)
```